# wordpress permalink and https and folder redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I "inherited" a website at the department I am working at that is hosted on a machine we don't have root access to. I managed to force https with the .htaccess file, but I was unable to add wordpress permalinks to it also. The combinations I tried all ended up pointing every link to the front page.

This is the .htaccess we have now (the wordpress website is in a subdirectory):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^familydogproject.elte.hu$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wordpress/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And this is the example wordpress gave for the permalinks:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does anybody have any idea how to combine them?

Comment: Someone voted to close this erroneously. This is not about general computing. Whoever that was, please retract your vote.

Comment: To the OP: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "ended up pointing every link to the front page". Do you mean that if a request is made to `/test/`, the home page is served?

Comment: @MikeRockett yes, clicking on any link loaded the home page.

Comment: I think your `RewriteBase` needs to be set to `/wordpress/`. Also make sure all your `href`s point to the correct directory.